# AngularJS validating outside of a form

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

I have a more or less complex SPA with ~40 text input fields. Those input elements are not bundled by a `<form>`, but they are separated into categories. If a user submits, i would like to trigger a validation function.

My first approach was writing two directives, one for string input and one for numeric values, which would add an attribute to every invalid element, then using a `validate()` function which would look up every input field in order to check whether or not it has said attribute.

I stumbled over multiple issues, including the fact that this was a jQuery like solution to the problem.

How could i accomplish this in a more convenient way?

Comment: it would be easier to answer with at least some data, validation can be done in so many ways it would help to know what you want more precisely

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I have been handling form validation when things are not inside of a form is by using ng-pattern.  With ng-pattern you can either do direct regex there, or link to an expression to run a set of validations for you.

It would look something like this.

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="Put your Regex Here or an Expression">
```

The angular docs for ng-pattern are pretty sparse, so good luck.

This approach may not be what you are looking for since it evaluates only one input at a time, but I hope this helps.